# I am trying to merge two CSV files and rearrange their columns using pandas in python, but am having trouble with an identical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas in python.

Both of my files start with an identical "tissue" column and I am getting those tissues repeated as a result. The information connected to "tissue" from each separate file comes in as the same row as the tissue from the separate files, resulting in a number of NAN data spaces. I am trying to remove the duplicates from the first column and the NAN data from the following columns.

```
    import pandas as pd

#defining both files
df1 = pd.read_csv('Aaron test 2-CLDN3.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Aaron test 2-CLDN4.csv')


#combining files into one
combined = pd.concat([df1, df2])

#selecting column order
result_df = combined[['Tissue','mean(CLDN3)','mean(CLDN4)','var(CLDN3)','var(CLDN4)']]

print (result_df)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPXak.png)

Comment: try `df = df1.combine_first(df2)`, if row is not aligned with `Tissue`, set it to index first: `df = df1.set_index('Tissue').combine_first(df2.set_index('Tissue'))

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Such an easy solution for something that's plagued me for an hour.